# windows ask for pen drive to be formatted?

Tags: windows-xp, usb-storage

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“Need to format the USB Flash drive” message… can the data be recovered.](https://superuser.com/questions/38382/need-to-format-the-usb-flash-drive-message-can-the-data-be-recovered)
>   [How to recover a USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/51984/how-to-recover-a-usb-flash-drive)

Hi Guys,

i have a newly bought kingston 4Gb pendrive, i have bought it month ago and been working with it up to now, my whole acedemic work is on that!today when i plugged my ped drive to the windowsXp machine, it didn't worked, and windows says it need to be formatted? i can't format the pen drive because i have my assignments work on that,please help me guys, i'm in a big trouble now! :(

many thanks in advance!

regards,
Rangana

Comment: duplicate of ["Need to format the USB Flash drive" message... can the data be recovered.](http://superuser.com/questions/38382/need-to-format-the-usb-flash-drive-message-can-the-data-be-recovered)

Comment: see also [How to recover a USB flash drive](http://superuser.com/questions/51984/how-to-recover-a-usb-flash-drive).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if it can detect on any other pc or laptop, maybe a friends. You will also need to use a recovery software like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) in order that you can retrieve the data.

And please stop using flash drives as your primary storage device, keep a backup somewhere if you do so.

Comment: i checked it with serveral other PCs but not laptops, they all had the windowsXp operating system! all of them are giving the same problem! :(

Comment: try one with a different OS

Comment: i tried it with windows 7 also, it didn't worked??

Comment: you should take a look at the answer in this link, it speaks of running test disk and it seems to have solved the problem http://superuser.com/questions/38382/need-to-format-the-usb-flash-drive-message-can-the-data-be-recovered

Comment: Here's a link to download Testdisk http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk I hope this work out for you. the partition table of your drive could be corrupted. I haven't tried this, but its worth a shot if it was successful for someone else