# Broken USB disk

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure

Somehow my USB flash drive is broken. When I plug it into my Windows 7 PC it appears in Windows Explorer, but I cannot format/access it; I get the "insert disk" message every time I try to access/format the drive.

What can I do to get it working again?

Comment: Do you have any important data on it that you want to keep?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Need to format the USB Flash drive" message... can the data be recovered](http://superuser.com/questions/38382/need-to-format-the-usb-flash-drive-message-can-the-data-be-recovered)

Comment: Fortunately not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any details about the drive it's hard to provide any detailed steps to help you. The fallback thing to do is try it on a different machine - Windows and something else, too. Sometimes Mac or Linux machines might be able to see it.
If they don't recognize it, you're probably out of luck. There may be a specific utility for your flash drive that might help.
In my experience though, a dead USB stick is dead. It's not even worth the shipping to RMA it unless it's a very pricey model.

Comment: There aren't much details, the drive is just recognized as "Generic USB Flash Disk USB Device". It has 4GB, I got it as a giveaway.

Comment: Fair enough. It was free so no big loss to you. However try this utility [SD Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/). Also, if you can see the drive in your BIOS there is hope, so you may want to check that out first.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried both of them, it neither shows up in my BIOS nor in SD Fomatter. Apparently I have to ditch the drive :(